# Why the $\pm$ sign after taking square root is considered only the positive one while showing validity of the expression?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

I was trying to derive the relation $\cos(\sin^{-1} x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Here is my working.

Consider the $\arcsin x$ belonging in $[0, \pi/2]$ range, then $x= \sin\theta$. Now, $\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}= \sqrt{1-x^2} = \cos\theta$.  Taking $\arccos$ of both sides as $\theta$ is lying between $[0 , \pi/2]$ so $\cos^{-1}\cos\theta = \theta$. This proves for one case.

Now, consider second case of $\arcsin x$ being lying in $[-\pi/2, 0]$. In this situation, we consider $-\theta$ it will belong to $[0,\pi/2]$ in range of $\arccos$, also as $\cos^{-1}\cos(-\theta) = \cos^{-1}\cos(\theta)$. Hence, it's equal to $-\theta$, so I got $\sin^{-1}x = \cos^{-1}(\sqrt{1-x^2})$ only for $x\geq 0$ and $-\cos^{-1}(\sqrt{1-x^2})$ for $x \leq 0$. Is there anything I have done wrong ?

Also, one step which I don't have a argument as to how to rectify it when we are taking square root we should get $\pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$. How to give a reason to reject one of them? Similarly, when we did $\sin\theta = \pm \sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}$?

Comment: The image of arcsine is $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. Cosine is positive on this interval.

Comment: Oh i see thanks @mr_e_man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We wish to show that $\cos(\arcsin x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$.

Let $\arcsin x = \theta$.  Then $\theta$ is the unique angle in the interval $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ such that $\sin\theta = x$.

By the Pythagorean identity,
$$\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$$
Subtracting $\sin^2\theta$ from each side of the equation yields
$$\cos^2\theta = 1 - \sin^2\theta$$
Substituting $x$ for $\sin\theta$ yields
$$\cos^2\theta = 1 - x^2$$
Since $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$, taking square roots yields
$$|\cos\theta| = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$$
Since $\cos\theta \geq 0$ in the interval $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$, $|\cos\theta| = \cos\theta$.  Thus,
$$\cos\theta = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$$
Finally, substituting $\arcsin x$ for $\theta$ yields
$$\cos(\arcsin x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$$